# "Pending checkins" window stuck; never finishes updating

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

I'm having a strange problem in Visual Studio 2008 where my "Pending Checkins" window never updates.  I open it up, and it says "Updating..." like usual, but I never see the "X remaining" message, and nothing happens.  It just sits there doing nothing.

Checked-out stuff still shows as checked out in Solution Explorer.  SourceSafe 2005 still works like normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried checking everything in, and then refreshing your workspace, and then checkout a file to see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "refreshing my workspace", but the problem occurs whether or not I have anything checked out, and it's been this way since yesterday.  And I've rebooted since yesterday.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hooray!  I found a solution.  For anyone else that stumbles across this, here's the deal.

I discovered today that the Pending Checkins window wasn't broken for *all* solutions, but only for a particular one.  Also, though I didn't realize it was related, every time I opened the solution, I was getting:

**"Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read."**

The solution I found was [here](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/rick/archive/2007/12/06/quot-some-of-the-properties-associated-with-the-solution-could-not-be-read-quot.aspx).  It turns out that I had two

```
GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution
```

sections in the solution (.sln) file.  I deleted the second one (which had a long list of projects, but also some gibberish in it), and the message went away, and my Pending Checkins window now works perfectly.

Comment: You Rock!.. I never got an error, but only in one of my solutions would the pending checkins window not update.  Checked the solution file, removed the duplicate SourceCodeControl section and bang.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Visual SourceSafe 2005 Update patch?

Comment: I have, and when I run the patch, I get this: "Error applying transforms.  Verify that the specified transform paths are valid."  :(